# Bounds on the support of a correlation matrix' eigenvalue spectrum

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, correlation, positive-definite, upper-lower-bounds

I have a covariance matrix $V=(v_{ij})$ and construct a correlation matrix $C$ with entries $c_{ij}=\frac{v_{ij}}{\sqrt{v_{ii}v_{jj}}}$. The matrices $V$ and $C$ are positive definite, so I know that the eigenvalues of $V$ and $C$ are real and positive. I am looking for a lower bound on $C$'s smallest eigenvalue and an upper bound on $C$'s largest eigenvalue.

My first idea was to make use of the bound on elements of $C$. I know that all diagonal elements of $C$ are $c_{ii}=1$ and that all non-diagonal elements $c_{ij}\in[-1,1]$. Using the Gershgorin circle theorem, all eigenvalues of $C$ lie in an interval $[1-n,1+n]$, where $n$ is the number of rows and columns in $C$.

I expect that one can do much better than this, perhaps by including a bit of information about the spectrum of $V$. For example, if the support of the spectrum of $V$ is a subset of an interval $[a,b]$, can we deduce bounds for the support of $C$ from this?

Comment: All the eigenvalues satisfy $0\le\lambda\le n$, since they are non-negative and add up to $n$.

Comment: @Alice Schwarze, do you have any constraints on the distribution of the $v_{ij}$ terms? The reason I ask is that for wide classes of random matrices (e.g., IID Gaussian coefficients), the top eigenvalue has a universal Tracy-Widom distribution, owing to the Kardar-Parisi-Zhang universality class. I believe there are similar controls on other eigenvalues, esp. the bottom one, and thus you can use large-deviations estimates to bound the eigenvalues via the distributional tail. In general, however, where the coefficients can correlated or have heavy tails, I don't know if you get useful bounds.